# why from my eclipse R file is deleted?

Tags: android

Gen folder is in project explorer  but R file is not there.
it showing error on the (R.layou.main).

```
package org.example.Wardrobe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Start extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any layout file named `main.xml` in your layout folder? If you have the file, then try a clean-build and see error window for possible errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a clean from Project->Clean and then Build the project again. That should get the R class generated again and your errors should disappear.

Comment: @Houcine: Yeah. OP asked a question specifically about Eclipse.. or am i missing something?

Comment: yeah i think that's Eclipse IDE , but he didn't mensionne that on his question , anyway , your answer is the solution , i've voted for it from the first ;)

Answer (score 2):

There will be some error in one of your xml file. fix that error, save your project and rebuild. R. java will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when Eclipse doesn't generate the `R.java` file is when there is a problem occuring somewhere. Do you really have a `main.xml` layout? If you are sure that everything is fine, do a `Project -> Clean` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try one more time create one more project then check R.java exist or not.if not then there is some problem in installation process.i installed and R.java file exist in it.